# How to implement a generic interface which implements another interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I've been having this problem for quite sometime. I have an interface, let's say, `ITransaction`. Now I need to create an interface called `IVolatileTransaction<T>`, which has to implement `ITransaction`, but `T` also has to be an `ITransaction`.

```
public interface IVolatileTransaction<T> : ITransaction
public interface IVolatileTransaction<T> where T : ITransaction
```

The problem is, I need both. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have tried, you'd have got the answer. `public interface IVolatileTransaction<T> :ITransaction where T : ITransaction`

Comment: Just to purify: an interface does not implement anything, it's inheritance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with this:

```
public interface ITransaction
{

}

public interface IVolatileTransaction<T> : ITransaction where T : ITransaction
{

}
```